# Error when trying store the return value of map insert

Tags: c++, c++11

```
map<int, set<int> > map_set;
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < rand()%50 + 20; ++i)  {
    int k = rand()%10, v = rand()%10;
    pair<map<int, set<int> >::iterator, bool> ret = map_set[k].insert(v);
    if (!ret.second)
        cout << "Attempted to insert [" << k << ":" << v << "], but entry already existed [" << ret.first->first << ":" << ret.first->second << "]" << endl; 
}
```

I am getting the following error in the line where I define `ret`:

```
[Error] conversion from 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>' to non-scalar type 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::set<int> > >, bool>' requested
```

It looks like the compiler is telling me that I did not declare `ret` as a `pair<map<int, set<int> >::iterator, bool>` but as some other thing I can't figure out.

I don't know what's wrong because doing the same thing in this different way works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rand()%50 + 20; ++i) 
    if (!(map_set[rand()%10].insert(rand()%10)).second)
        cout << "Failed attempt to insert value for a new key: it already existed" << endl;
```

Comment: `ret`'s type is for insertions into a `map<int,set<int>>`. But `map_set[k].insert(v)` is inserting into a `set<int>`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a helpdesk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `insert` refers to the [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) therefore the return type should be:

```
std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool> ret = map_set[k].insert(v);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d192166cb865dc9)

If you can use C++11, you should probably look into [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), that will simplify the call to:

```
auto ret = map_set[k].insert(v);
```

Comment: thank you that was it, how couldn't I have noticed! also I love how people downvotes so happily

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question is not likely to ever help anyone in the future. Rudimentary syntax questions are not really helpful for anyone but you, so it probably warrents being downvoted or closed. As long as you got your answer, no harm no foul :)